# Check if there are JMS messages on Glassfish 3 cluster nodes

Tags: jms, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I'm trying to check if there are messages on a queue. To access the queue I'm using a Connection Factory, a Destination Resource and JNDI lookup (method below). The problem comes when the Connection Factory points to multiple nodes from a Glassfish 3 cluster. The *AddressList* property has the list with ip addresses of the nodes.

One way to solve it, would be to check each node. Is there a way to read the value of the *AddressList* property from a JMS Connection Factory defined in the Glassfish resources ?

Are there any other ways to check if there are messages on a queue on all the nodes of a Glassfish 3 cluster ?

Wouldn't like to save the addresses of the cluster nodes both in a configuration file and in the JMS Connection Factory (the Connection Factory is already used in some other parts of the application).

Thanks.

```
private boolean existsMessagesOnTheQueue(String connectionFactoryName, Queue queue, String selector) throws Exception {
    QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    QueueConnection connection;
    Session session ;
    QueueBrowser browser ;
    try {
        connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) InitialContext.doLookup(connectionFactoryName);
        connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        browser = session.createBrowser(queue, selector);

        connection.start();

        if (browser.getEnumeration().hasMoreElements()) {
            log.debug("Found message on " + queue.getQueueName());
            return true;
        }
    } finally {
        closeBrowser(browser);
        closeSession(session);
        closeConnection(connection);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if the connection factory lists multiple nodes in its AddressList attribute, it is sufficient to check for messages in any ONE of these addresses. All the other copies in the cluster would have the same messages.
From [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2438/gheav.html#aeoep):

> In a broker cluster, you create a physical destination on one broker and the cluster propagates it to all the others. Because the brokers cooperate to route messages across the cluster, client applications can consume messages from destinations on any broker in the cluster.

The above mentions about clients `consuming` messages from any broker in the cluster. So, `Browsing` could also be done through any broker.

Comment: Unfortunately, the queues from the cluster have different messages. In one case, a queue was empty, while the other queues had messages.

Comment: That means clustering is not really working and that is a whole different problem. All I am saying in my answer here is that the solution for that is not to browse all copies of a queue across the cluster. I would suggest to create a new question with your cluster config on why your clustering is not working.